# Automatic Login via OAuth, Trello-style?

Tags: authentication, web-applications, oauth, oauth-2.0

I really like Trello's login style-- after i'm logged into Gmail, calendars, anything, i'm automatically logged in when i get to their site.

What i can't find is a complete example of how to go about this sort of "automatic login"-- in any language. While i'd prefer something in .NET, I'm open to whatever.

Any help on resources that detail how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

They are not using OAuth system rather than they are using OpenID protocol and once you approve the authentication as per this you will again not asked to approve it again.

More over for the first time when you go there it present a check-box to remember the approval

What you looking is similar to what SO is providing, once you have register with SO anytime you to google login page and if you are logged in you will automatically get logged in a part of OpenID

for .net here is the one SO itself using

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)